# Estimate Current Requirements Of A Circuit

Tags: microcontroller, avr, current, current-measurement

So far with all my electronics circuits I have been using a DC wallwart so didn't have to think much about the current requirements of my circuits.

Now I have a prototype that I would like to run using a battery (ideally with 2 coin cells @ 3V each in series but a 9V battery would also do).

I get the basic idea that all batteries are rated at mAh so if I know the max current used by my circuit I can estimate the time the battery would last.

But the details confuse me. With a simple micrcontoller circuit this can easily easily be done by looking up the the max current draw from the microcontroller datasheet. However in my circuit I have a microcontroller connected to various LEDs', a LCD screen (savaged from an old mobile phone), a Bluetooth serial UART and a LM317 voltage converter IC (to step down to 3.3V for LCD).

How do I figure out the current requirements with all these peripherals in my circuit ?

Comment: Instead of trying to calculate every detail, I would suggest you to connect your multimeter and measure the current drawn in real-time. However, there is a problem with that, called "Burden Voltage". To overcome this problem, check [this](http://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/) out.

Comment: I'm curious as to how these big electronics companies do this ... I mean before designing a prototype they must have some idea given the design constraints they are working with (eg: the final product must be able to run of a single 3V coin cell)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the datasheets of the devices and your circuit. The naive way is to add all currents up, which will give you the absolut maximum current draw (if all your devices are in parallel). You will get a more precise estimation by looking at your schematic and applying [Kirchoffs Current Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) (KCL). If you have a prototype already, you can always measure.

Comment: Erm, suha, the boss wants to know by noon, not in two months.

Comment: @stevenvh a less cryptic message would be appreciated

Comment: Your method is thorough, but takes *a lot* of time. You can't spend weeks on this, because that's what it will take. For an estimate like this you usually get a couple of hours.

Comment: @stevenvh you have the schematic, write the amount current you know from the datasheet on each path and do the math (simple addition and substraction) on the rest until you end up at the power source. Unless you have hundreds and hundreds of parts this could be done in an hour (maybe two, but definitely in a day). I think you should be willing to put that much thought into a design. Paper is cheap and fast. In the end you can even check for errors easier, since you can measure the actual currents in the prototype and find out where your thinking was differnent from what actually happens.

Comment: The designs I've worked on so far are not exactly the exercises from a textbook, where you have a resitor network you have to calculate. Yes, for a start there are hundreds of components, many ICs with lots of pins, which have god-knows-what current. Complex impedances with complex signals. No way you can do this in an hour. Not even on paper.

Comment: @stevenvh your designs may have been quite complex, but the one pointed out in the original post seems to be rather simple and with a handful of components.

Comment: My point is that this is not a good way to do it in general.

Comment: @stevenvh ok, and i focused on the circuit given in the question.